# Does the equation $\mathbf{I} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{U} \mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{A}_k$ have a special name or solution?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-equations

I have encountered the equation $\mathbf{I} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}_k$, recently.

All matrices are of dimension $n \times n$.

Is it assigned a special name?

I'm trying to find a closed form or efficient approximate solution for it.

Do you know any solution or reference?

Comment: in relation to your previous similar question: please don't delete questions after you have received a lot of feedback, in consideration for others who might benefit from that feedback --- http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255081/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-to-compute-left-mathbfu-n-times-m-mathbf

Comment: Not sure if it helps but with a formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)  the equation becomes equivalent to $$vec(X^{-1})=\left(\sum_k A_k^T \otimes B_k\right)vec(X^T)$$ where $vec\colon \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{9}$ denotes the vectorization.